# How to set the pixels of an image to black in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to open an image and set all of its pixels to black.
I have this code that compiles but produces an empty transparent png. I was expecting a black image.

```
extern crate image;                                                                   
                                                                                      
use image::{GenericImageView, ImageBuffer, RgbaImage, imageops, Rgba};
                                                                                                  
fn main() {
    let img = image::open("images/image1.png").unwrap();
                                                                                                                                                                    
    let (width, height) = img.dimensions();
    let mut out: RgbaImage = ImageBuffer::new(width, height);

    for pixel in out.enumerate_pixels_mut() {
        *pixel.2 = image::Rgba([255,255,255,1]);
    }

     out.save("out.png").unwrap();
}
```

Comment: `[255,255,255,1]` is transparent white. Did you mean `[0,0,0,255]`?

Comment: @mousetail You're right. I mixed up 255 and 0 and didn't realize the alpha channel was not encoded as a float between 0 and 1. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[255,255,255,1]` is a white image.

You need to use the following `[0,0,0,255]`. In rust the transparency is not encoded as a float unlike in js runtime with the browser for instance.

Comment: You're right about 0,0,0 being black but the alpha channel must be set to 255.